# Whitespace collapse between inline elements

Tags: html, css, whitespace

The following puts the red box on the right:

```css
.wrap {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.wrap:before {
  content: " ";
  margin: 0 -50px 0 100%;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

But if you set the `content` value to an empty string, i.e. `content: "";`, the red box no longer stays on the right in Webkit browsers, e.g. Chrome. What exactly is going on here? Is it a bug in Webkit or in other browsers?

Comment: Please explain the issue in detail.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Interesting. I thought it had something to do with the before's right margin of 100%, and the solution would have been to use `margin:0 0 0 calc(100% - 50px)` instead, but that didn't work. Sorry. Meanwhile, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to move the box on the right side without changing its display property, you have at least two ways to do it:

**1st option**
1) Remove the space from the `.wrap:before` content
2) Add a comment between `.wrap` and `.box`:

```
<div class="wrap"><!--
  --><div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

**2nd option**
Use the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  text-align: right;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: As I said on the other answer, I don't think this answers OPs question. He is curious as to **why**  he is seeing the explained behavior, not particularly looking for workarounds.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I tested this with Firefox which uses different engine the rendered output looks the same no matter if there is a space in `content` of `.wrap:before` or it is empty. I assume this is a problem with Webkit.